# How to make two column and input box below them ? Like that:

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have problem with my code. I can't make the design who i will upload here. I can't make two column and below them input box who will be show when the button is pressed.
Design that i want to be:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSz78.png)
Here is my code HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="raboti.css">-->
     <h1>Calculator</h1>
     
     <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="withbootstat.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     
     <div class="row">
      <div class="dropDown" style="background-color: #efefef;">
       <h2>Брой служители:</h2>
        <select id="mySelect">
         <option value="1">1-10</option>
         <option value="2">11-30</option>
         <option value="3">31-80</option>
         <option value="4">81-150</option>
         <option value="5">151-300</option>
         <option value="6">300+</option>
        </select>
        
      </div>
    
      <div class="dropDown" id="monthCost" style="background-color: #efefef;">
       <h2>Месечен разход(лв.):</h2> <input type="text" id="ourSum">
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <div class="row1">
      <div class="sum" id="finalSum">
       При нас цената ще е: <input class="hide type="text" id="result" >
       <br><button type="button" onclick="sum()">Изчисли</button>
    
      </div>
     </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is code that i got from w3school for two columns..
And here is my CSS code:

```
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .dropDown {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */

    }
    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
        .dropDown {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .row1 {
        margin-top: -200px;
        margin-left: 100px;
    }
    .hide{
      display:none;
    }
    .show{
      display:block;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the CSS you have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your photo, you can achieve what you want with [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```css
.flex-center {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-justify-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.mr-50 {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.ml-50 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.round-box {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.grow {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.p-40 {
  padding: 40px;
}

.pt-0 {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.pr-40 {
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.pl-40 {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: #00B6FD;
  color: white;
}

.text-blue {
  color: #00348C;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-center flex-column flex-wrap text-blue">
  <div class="d-flex flex-center flex-column">
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-center flex-justify-around w-100 flex-wrap">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column grow p-40 pt-0">
      <h4>Question</h4>
      <input type="text" class="round-box " id="bx-1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column grow p-40 pt-0">
      <h4>Answer</h4>
      <input type="text" class="round-box" id="bx-1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" class="round-box pl-40 pr-40 bg-blue font-weight-bold"/>
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/wQRyrG) :)

On a side note, this one should be responsive as well ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It helped me a lot !

Comment: @PetrovD please don't forget to vote and mark this as answer it it's a solution to your question and sure, happy coding! :)